Why is my Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) score higher than my Speed Index (SI) score?
I'm doing some work trying to improve my site's speed. I am running multiple Lighthouse tests and using the average to measure improvements I make.
I have a question about LCP and Speed Index.
As I understand it, the LCP score is the time it takes to render the largest contentful element within the viewport. For me this averages 3.3 seconds.
The Speed Index metric "measures how quickly content is visually displayed during page load" within the viewport. For me this averages 2.2 seconds.
My question is, wouldn't LCP count towards to the Speed Index metric? Shouldn't my Speed Index be at least as slow as the LCP (3.3+s)?

Speed Index captures the visual completeness of the entire viewport, not just the largest element visible in the viewport.
So if any smaller elements above the fold show up quickly, they can positively influence the Speed Index metric, even if the LCP takes longer to load.
The reason it's this way is because the Speed Index metric is based on render timing; it's about progression over time. If much of the above fold section becomes visible quickly, then you're likely going to see a lower/better score despite a lagging LCP.
In your case, it sounds like users would see most of the content fairly quickly, and then the LCP pops in a second later. Typically, I see this when there's media above the fold loading asynchronously.
Note about lab tests
I would not be quick to judge based on Lighthouse score unless you think a slow-4g connection is realistic for a majority of your users.
The whole reason you're doing this is for Google, and the Page Experience algorithm looks at Core Web Vitals scores clocked from field data.
So before you invest too much time and energy in improving this any further, I'd try and get some RUM data first and then see where you're at.

" If much of the above fold section becomes visible quickly, then you're likely going to see a lower/better score despite a lagging LCP."  - so is it measuring the majority of the viewport being rendered?

I don't know if that's exactly the correct way to put it, but yes, that's essentially correct.
